# How to reset emulator DB before each test?

Tags: gcloud-node

I'm running tests with the gcloud datastore emulator for node.
I want to reset the db before each test.

Is there a quick way like a 'drop' command or something I can use in a beforeEach block ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simply remove the db file. Usually, it is `~/.config/gcloud/emulators/datastore/WEB-INF/appengine-generated/local_db.bin`.

Comment: How can I do that in a beforeEach block with mocha ? I'm not sure that will work while the emulator is already up. It expects some file to exist during session.

Comment: Just delete the file, you can use `del` or `rimraf` for that. Tested it, I can delete `local_db.bin` while emulator is running, and it works fine.

Comment: ok thanks ! Since I want to do it in a beforeEach block, I used node fs module

Answer (score 1):

You could also send a `POST /reset` request to the emulator, mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47007653/1332865).