# Google Datastore emulator remove data from local database

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a local Datastore emulator instance running on my local machine (Mac OSX 10.11.6).

I have a bunch of data in there already, but I want to remove all data from the local database to start with a clean slate.

However I have already tried deleting the directory (where I thought) the data was being stored.

This message appears when starting the emulator.

```
WARNING: Reusing existing data in [/Users/myusername/.config/gcloud/emulators/datastore].
```

I deleted the entire datastore directory and it seems to be re-generated properly when the emulator is restarted. However, the old data is still there.

```
rm -rf /Users/myusername/.config/gcloud/emulators/datastore
```

I also confirmed that my Node App is connecting to the local emulator.

```
myusername$ $(gcloud beta emulators datastore env-init)
myusername$ gcloud beta emulators datastore env-init
export DATASTORE_DATASET=projectname
export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8081
export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST_PATH=localhost:8081/datastore
export DATASTORE_HOST=http://localhost:8081
export DATASTORE_PROJECT_ID=projectname
```

Comment: Were the emulator/app running when you removed the dir?

Comment: This duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/q/39027941/1332865

Answer (score 9):

Datastore emulator supports resetting datastore when its running. This can be used to reset datastore when running tests.

Make `POST` request to `http://localhost:8081/reset` to clear the internal state of the emulator i.e

```
curl -X POST http://<emulator-host>:<port>/reset
```

see [https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues/1292](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues/1292#issuecomment-250391120|) discussion

Comment: this just hangs for me, or maybe takes a long time for the data that I have. GAEfan's answer is much easier/quicker/actually works.

Answer (score 3):

1. Stop the local dev server from running
2. Find its `dev_appserver.datastore` file and drag it to the trash
3. Restart dev server

A new, empty local datastore will be created.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea where I can find this file? I tried finding it using the find command but doesn't seem to be returning any results.
$ sudo find / -name *.datastore

Comment: I assumed you knew where it was, as you said you deleted its folder.  Are you using the `--datastore_path` flag when you start the project?

Comment: on my machine it's at <my_gcp_store>/WEB-INF/appengine-generated/db_store.bin

Comment: On Mac, the default is `~/.config/gcloud/emulators/datastore`